# Can knitr deal with multiple .Rmd files in the same directory?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am using knitr to generate markdown that I then convert to html using `markdown::markdownToHTML()`

`knitr` will place figures for .Rmd file in a `figure/` subdirectory. If I process multiple .Rmd files in the same directory, however, the figures can get overwritten.  Naming each chunk with a name that is unique across all .Rmd files makes uniquely named figures, but that is error prone.  Reusing a name by accident will silently overwrite older figures.

Is there an easy way to use different `figure/` directories or otherwise separate the figures for each .Rmd file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "other_directory")
```

In each document to override the default `figure/` path.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that.

Comment: if you are cacheing any chunks, you want to set  `cache.path`, too.